# Typescript Object Syntax Question (has no index signature)

Tags: typescript

I'm converting some legacy code like this:

```
var storage = {
  _cache:{},
  setCache:function(key, value){
    storage._cache[key] = value;
  }
}
```

In Typescript, `storage._cache[key] = value;` throws an error:

```
TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature.
```

What are the various syntaxes to replicate the example above?

The only way I can figure it out, without making a huge interface for the entire object, is to create my object with the index signature outside of the object first:

```
let aMap:{ [code:string] : any } = {};
let storage = {
  _cache:map 
}
```

But I'd rather do this inline.  I'm looking for something more like:

```
let storage = {
  _cache: { [code:string] : any } : {},   <-- this dont work obviously
  setCache:function...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a huge interface for the entire object, you can simply do:

```
interface IStorage {
    [code: string]: any;
    setCache: (key: string, value: any) => void;
}

let storage: IStorage = {
    _cache: {},
    setCache:function(key, value){
    storage._cache[key] = value;
  }
}
```

And it is better to type the whole object, it makes your code cleaner and easier to reason about.

OR if you really want to inline it, then you can do:

```
let storage: { [code: string]: any} = {
 _cache: {},
 setCache:function(key, value){
   storage._cache[key] = value;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your inline example helped me. ```const $qPredicates: { [key:string]: string } = {
    "="     : "==",
    "!="    : "!=",
    ">"     : "=gt=",
    ">="    : "=ge=",
    "<"     : "=lt=",
    "<="    : "=le=",
    "~"     : ""
};```